# When I add .jpg photos to photoshop why don't they size proportionately?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I have two .jpg images I am trying to add into photoshop see details in screenshots below (note the dimensions of the photos):

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsXX6.jpg) (Dimensions: 655x1000)

[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVOJX.jpg) (Dimensions: 1016x1500)

Note how photo 2 is bigger than photo 1, however, when I drag them into photoshop, the result looks like this:

[image]

**Image 1 shows up significantly larger than image 2, even though the dimensions of image 2 are listed as much bigger. Why is this happening? Am I missing something here?**

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please check if both images have the same PPI setting. If not, that's probably it.

Comment: @BillyKerr both of them are 72PPI according to Photoshop

Answer (score 1):

The images in your PSD are not normal layers, but smart objects. Obviously they have now their original millimeter dimensions which are taken from the metadata.

No worry! You can scale them forth and back without losing anything from the original quality because they are smart objects. Scaling is always calculated from the original data, unsharpness doesn't cumulate.